# How to change file association without UAC confirmation?

Tags: c#, .net, uac, file-association

When I was working with file association in a .NET application I hadn't had found a way to set it without UAC popping up a confirmation dialog.

Today, when I opened uTorrent and looked up for file association, I've found that you can enable (writing to registry) without any confirmation from the UAC.

How is that possible? uTorrent is not running as an admin.

**Edit:**

Well, I have just discovered with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (Sysinternals) that what uTorrent.exe does is to create a few keys (**uTorrent** and **.torrent**) but in **HKCU** (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`), not in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.
Anyways I also have those keys in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` ... maybe the installer created those. Not sure.

Comment: Are you sure it's changing system wide settings?

Comment: Yes, it's adding keys to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Comment: I believe that some of the registry may be virtualized so that the changes are only effective for your profile.  Log in as a different user and see if it really made a system wide change.

Comment: You're right ... only affects your profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this article in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530198.aspx) about the global registry being virtualized so that the changes are only effective for your user profile.