# C++: How do I correctly register and unregister file type associations for our application (programatically)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-association

Time was when you set file associations in:

HEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<.ext>

However, that seems to be possible, but an incomplete solution anymore.  There are additional associations throughout the registry.  For example:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Extensions

And all of the above, but by HKEY_USERS\

And Microsoft added their Set Default Associations control panel applet, which controls... what?

I'm looking for a white paper, or discussions on:

**"How is a modern, Windows XP-Windows 7 compatible application written in C/C++ supposed to register and manipulate its file associations without interfering with Explorer, User-Settings, or the Default Associations cpl"**

EDIT: I'm trying to further this investigation with more questions here:
[How to delete ProgIDs from other user accounts when uninstalling from Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850157/how-to-delete-progids-from-other-user-accounts-when-uninstalling-from-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, this documentation still seems current, and it's all about the registry: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144148(VS.85).aspx)

Maybe someone's created a nice wrapper for this? Time to hit Google...

Comment: The docs are long & convoluted, but everything I needed appears to be available from here.  It would be peachy if there was a good summary someplace, but cest la vie.  I should be able to rebuild our extension registration system to be per-user aware, and I could even extend it to integrate default-program shell services, though that sounds like overkill for us.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Microsoft wants you to do this through an installation package rather than on-the-fly, since you need elevated permissions to do so.

**Edit:** See this previous StackOverflow question for how this might be possible.

[How to change file association without UAC confirmation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562386/how-to-change-file-association-without-uac-confirmation)

Comment: But there are apps (such as media players and graphics editors) where you select/deselect which types they should be associated with, long after installation.