# A Qt spreadsheet app shows stored files like unknown ones

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-installer

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebv4qvol49rrqd3/SP.rar?dl=0) is the program and below is the screenshot of the issue.

I using Qt Installer Framework (QtIFW2.0.1) created an installer for that Qt app (the spreadsheet). Then installed it on my PC. Now when I create a New File and then save it on the Desktop (Windows 7 x64), the app handles the file but its  shape is like unknown files!

Here are some samples:

[image]

I searched on the web and did these:

I edited the *package.xml* file and changed all `@component.addOperation` to `@component.addElevatedOperation` in the `installscript` file.
There were three `operations` all for creating shortcuts.

Now I seemingly should add this line of code into the code:

```
addElevatedOperation("GlobalConfig", "SystemScope", "Company", "App", "key", "value")
```

My question is, is it sufficient to solve the issue? And if so, where in the code, what `.h` or `.cpp` file to use it into, please?

If any other file is needed I will pleasantly upload it.

Comment: The icon windows shows for a file is linked with its extension.

Comment: Yes, and it probably needs to make changes in registery to see some shape on those icons. And any other program that we download and install from the market does this. That is they modify registery when installing, so their own file types will be shown specifically. I mean what to do to make my app do the same.

Comment: This post may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828637/c-how-do-i-correctly-register-and-unregister-file-type-associations-for-our-a